# Running Total To Exclude Supressed Value in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum, suppress

I wish to sum the data on display in my crystal report and not the suppressed data.

I have used the field editor and suppressed tool in the repeated area and I have the below formula for the rows to be suppressed:

```
{fieldname} = previous {fieldname}
```

I have read that if I use the running total and enter the opposite formula to subtotal then the subtotal will sum only the values displayed, e.g.

```
{fieldnmae} <> previous field-name.
```

However after doing this the first row is now totaling as the previous will be null. The report is sorted so the first row will always be a true value.  Is there a formula I can use to display this to sub total? E.g. if Previous {filedname} isnull or {fieldname} <> previous field-name = sub total.

Or is there another solutions to this?

The data looks something like

```
Row No Value 
0      20.00
0      20.00
1      25.00
2      10.00 
3      7.50
4      5.00
4      5.00
```

If row no repeated than do no sub total or display

Many Thanks !!!!!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be don't manipulate on `Value` column instead manipulate `Row No` column.

Create a running total and sum when `Row No` changes which will give correct results